# How to Register a COM dll for non administrative users

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com

My setup program has one COM dll which need to be registered.

I tried to run my setup program under win7 32 bit "standard user"  and it failed because COM dll registration which requires admin privilege. Except this, my application doesn't need any admin privilege to work.

Is there any way to resolve this issue. I need to run my application for non admin users.

Comment: Sorry, no. Registering a COM DLL sets registry keys that are only accessible from admin.

Comment: Use a reg-free COM manifest if you don't want to use an installer.  Do however ask yourself how you'll get your app copied into c:\program files.  That requires elevation as well.

Answer (score 4):

Per user registration (e.g. reg.exe import to HKCU) does not require admin. See [Non-Admin ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

COM Components do not need to be registered in order to be used.

You can use [CoRegisterClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register the IClassFactory interface for an object. This method works if you implement the COM object.

You can call LoadLibrary to get the [DllGetclassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) entrypoint to the dll, and create the object using the class factory directly.

You can create a simple XML file that exposes the COM dll as an assembly. Add the assembly as a dependent assembly of your application and you have [Registration Free Com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)